# PHP mysql Inserting data to a table based on another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm tring to insert data into a table based on the user on another table like: 
`personal_information,leave_table where personal_information.person_id=leave_table.person_id and personal_information.person_id=$person_id`

The user is applying for leave day but must insert the data into his own record 
I hope i'm being clear

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO leave_table (reqLeave, cause) VALUES (%s, %s)",
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['reqLeave'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['cause'], "text"));
    mysql_select_db($database_leaveReqForm, $leaveReqForm);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $leaveReqForm) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

update:

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {

```
$select_query = select pi.person_id from personal_information as pi INNER JOIN leave_table as lt ON pi.person_id=lt.person_id where pi.person_id = $person_id
$result = mysql_query($select_query);
$no = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($no > 0)
{
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO leave_table (reqLeave, cause) VALUES (%s, %s)",
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['reqLeave'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['cause'], "text"));
mysql_select_db($database_leaveReqForm, $leaveReqForm);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $leaveReqForm) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

}

> `Blockquote`

Comment: and the problem/issue is?

Comment: what is the SQL query to do that? right now when I request leave day it is stored in a new field not same person_id who requested it

Comment: what do you mean with *but must insert the data into his own record*?

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated use pdo instead just sidenode and there arre many validation functions in php

Comment: when the user requesting leave days, i want it update his old request where person_id from the table is matching personal_information person_id from the table leave_table

Comment: great, then show us your datavase structure, obviosly we cannot quess what kind of INSERT you must do from the code above.

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
 $select_query = "select pi.person_id from personal_information as pi INNER JOIN leave_table as lt ON pi.person_id=lt.person_id where pi.person_id ='".$_POST['person_id']."'" 
    $result = mysql_query($select_query);
    $no = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($no > 0)
    {
        insert/update here
    }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'pi' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\HRMS\employee_leave.php on line 41

Comment: i need table leave_table to updated WHERE person_id =  personal_information.person_id that is all

Comment: write query in double or single quotes and where the requested person_id you have written?see i have updated answer.